# How to copy file based on partial filename in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to copy certain .JPG files from my photocard to another directory.  The files are named IMG_7853.JPG, IMG_7854.JPG, and so on (they range from IMG_0001.JPG to IMG_9999.JPG).  If I want to copy all files greater than IMG_7853 what's the best approach in python.  The code below works fine for listing all files in the directory, but I wasn't sure how to go about making the comparison based on the partial filename.

```
#! /bin/python
import re
import os

def copyphoto():
    path="/media/CANON_DC/DCIM"
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            if name.endswith(".JPG"):
                print name
```

Comment: What you need to do is extract the numeric portion, convert it to an integer, and make the comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
   if name.endswith(".JPG") and int( name.split("_")[-1].split(".")[0] ) > 7853 :
...
```

Comment: Thanks.  Thought it would be harder than that.

Answer (score 3):

[`fnmatch`](http://docs.python.org/library/fnmatch.html) does glob-style matching.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know python but you should be able to just compare them. As long as the files are strings and all start with IMG_ with no leading zeros, you should just be able to use IMG_7853.JPG > filename

Comment: Sorry - I didn't post in my original question that there are leading zeros for certain filenames.  I edited it to reflect this.

Comment: @matt_k: Actally, the leading zeros are *good*. Go ahead and try Tony's suggestion. It will only work *because* of the leading zeros.

Comment: @matt_k Ah okay, Those leading zeros are perfect. When i mentioned leading zero's that would hurt you i meant more of "IMG_700.JPG" compared to "IMG_0705.JPG". In this case, your "IMG_0705.JPG" would actually be less than your "IMG_700.JPG". Since they all have 4 digit numbers though you won't run into this problem.